# Hosting Private Sphinx Documentation

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I am currently writing some extensive documentation using Sphinx for a rather complex Django web site. I have been working on this in-house and before I leave soon I want to leave behind detailed documentation accessible by the new devs/admins for the site.

My question is what are my options for hosting this documentation? I would prefer it to be private. Also the docs are concerning a website not a python package. For these two reasons I am thinking that Read the Docs may not be the most appropriate option.

I ran across [django-sphinxdoc](http://stefan.sofa-rockers.org/docs/django-sphinxdoc/) , though this requires setting up Haystack as the backend. Is there not a way to simply server the docs using the built in js search? Or a service which allows private hosting of the docs?

Any options would be much appreciated.

Comment: I felt the same need to host documentation privately. So I have built a web service that supports private Sphinx documentation hosting: HasDocs. https://github.com/narrowcast/hasdocs.com It should eliminate the need to set up your own web server, etc. You can sync your GitHub repositories and permissions. Private projects have private docs that are accessible only by those with the right privileges. The documentation gets rebuilt whenever you push new code to your GitHub repository. It's currently in beta and supports Sphinx, Jekyll, and Javadoc as documentation generator. Please give it a try

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sphinx can generate static `.html` files (`make html`). Put those HTML files up on an internal web server and you should be good to go.

Comment: Does this work with the js search?

Comment: Yup. The JS search is just JS with a static index (which is built when you build your documentation).

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154383/making-sphinx-documentation-private?noredirect=1&lq=1) (full disclosure, I asked the question, got no answer did some research and coding and posted the answer, so while it works there may be better ones out there. I'd be much obliged if someone would point them out.)

This gitlab repo shows a working example [here](https://gitlab.com/rmenk/private-sphinx-test).

Uses [static password protection](https://github.com/matteobrusa/Password-protection-for-static-pages/blob/master/index.html) and is also discussed in this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/33422#note_41346218).